# jQuery bxSlider does not start at the right position

Tags: jquery, slider, position

I cannot find out what I am doing wrong. So far, I have tested this only in Internet Explorer, so it could be that Firefox and Chrome aren't parsing the code properly.

http://ontwikkelomgeving.wijzijnblits.nl/ginkelbemmelen/luuk/

My problem is that the bxSlider on the page will start approximately 20px to the right. I do not define this (as far as I know) so I don't know why this is happening. If you click the 1 button, then it slides to the right place.

Answer (score 8):

Add this style in slider1 **padding:0px !important;**

```
<ul id="slider1" style="list-style: none outside none;padding:0px !important;">
```

Answer (score 4):

Luuk or anyone else,

Add

```
style='margin:0 0 0 0;'
```

to the  tag at the start of your list of scrolling objects, completely sorted it for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Wherever there are functions with .outerHeight() or .outerWidth() calls, change this to ->
    `.outerWidth(true)`
    `.outerHeight(true)`

It does mean bxSlider count margins as well. It helps me to fix bad-position issues.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem. for `#slider1`, use `liststyle: none;` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed any problems like this for me was to activate the plugin after the page has loaded.

If you are using jquery, that do it like this

```
$(window).load(function() {
      //add your code here
)};
```

Mootools, it would be like this

```
$('document').addEvent('domready', function() { 
    //code here...
});
```